# hadoop mapreduce - API for getting job log

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I’m developing a hadoop mapreduce application and i need to present the end user the task log.
(same as hue does).

is there a java-api that extract the logs of specific job?

i tried "JobClient" API without any  success.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the [Job Attempts](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.4.1/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/HistoryServerRest.html) API of the [HistoryServer](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.4.1/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/HistoryServerRest.html) provides a link to the logs of each task

Comment: you can call REST from Java. A java API would do an RPC anyway since you are not running in the HistoryServer's JVM

Comment: it seems that the history is only for completed jobs.how can i get the log of the running jobs?

Comment: Through the ResourceManager Attempts API http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.2.0/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/ResourceManagerRest.html#Cluster_Application_Attempts_API

Comment: @ArnonRotem-Gal-Oz the links are broken

Comment: http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.6.0/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/ResourceManagerRest.html#Cluster_Application_Attempts_API